# Nextjs 13.4 permanentRedirect is not a function

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-redirects

I use pretty the same example as [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/permanentRedirect) does.

My full code (literally nothing more):

```
import React from "react";
import { redirect, permanentRedirect } from 'next/navigation'

export default function Index(params) {
  permanentRedirect('/licenseKeys')
}
```

For sure I can use `redirect()` function instead, but I need to mark this redirect as permanent.

I investigated the `next/navigation` file, and there is no `permanentRedirect()` function, only regular `redirect()`.

This looks like some stupid mistake like "one wrong character", but I copy-pasted the example from Next.js documentation, and nothing changed. Maybe somebody knows where I am wrong? Or is it Next.js docs lie to us?

The error:
[image: permanentRedirect is not a function]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is documented but not released yet.
It's already in the `canary` release. You can install it by `npm install next@canary` (use at your own risk).

The documentation of `peremanentRedirect` is made two weeks ago in [this pull request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/54047) But, the function is not yet released in a stable release.

Comment: That is strange that an unreleased feature is documented inside the main docs tree.